# How to replace a symbol in an input value with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have generated inputs with price values.

Example:

```
<input type="text" value="59,00"/>
```

Now I should replace the `,` (comma) with a `.` (dot) with jQuery.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
$('#inputid[value~=,]').each(function(i){    
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(',','.'))
});
```

Could you help me

Comment: you should use regular expression, http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Development/RegularExpressionsReplacingStringsviaRegularExpressions.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input:text').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(value.replace(/\,/i, '.'));
});
```